# Um campo da tabela 1 relacionado a 2 campos da tabela 2

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Suponhamos duas tabelas

Tabela 1 : emp (tabela de Funcionários)

```
Campos : emp.no (chave privaria), emp.name (chave múltipla, não primaria)
```

Tabela 2: webConferencia

```
Campos: webConferencia.no (chave primaria), webConferencia.conferenteno
(não primária, smallint), webConferencia.embaladorno (não primária, smallint)
```

Quero pegar o nome do funcionário (emp.name), sendo eles conferentes (`webConferencia.conferenteno`) e embalador (`webConferencia.embaladorno`), como relacionar 1 campo chave primaria de uma tabela com 2 campos de uma segunda tabela simultaneamente?

```
webConferencia.conferenteno = emp.no
webConferencia.embaladorno  = emp.no
```

Comment: consegui fazer juntando duas selects temporárias. Primeiros Fiz o left join com o campo conferenteno e depois na segunda temporaria fiz o left join com o campo embaladorno

Comment: Olá @Tiago Damasio se você conseguiu solucionar, adicione na sua resposta o código da sua solução ou um exemplo que ache útil compartilhar com o SO-pt.

Answer (score 1):

Se na tabela webConferencia sempre vai ter a referência de um funcionário você pode fazer apenas o `JOIN`.

Nos casos em que duas colunas se referem a chave primária de outra tabela pode fazer a *Query* dando um "apelido" diferente a mesma tabela quando se trata da outra coluna, veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT webConferencia.no, conferente.name, embalador.name
FROM webConferencia
JOIN emp conferente ON webConferencia.conferenteno = conferente.no /* emp apelidada de conferente */
JOIN emp embalador ON webConferencia.embaladorno = embalador.no /* emp apelidada de embalador */
```

> Nesse exemplo acima, pode notar que ficaram duas colunas name, se quiser identifica-las basta colocar um "apelido" nelas também assim como fez nas tabelas:

```
SELECT webConferencia.no, conferente.name conferente /* apelidada de conferente */, embalador.name embalador /* apelidada de embalador */
FROM webConferencia
JOIN emp conferente ON webConferencia.conferenteno = conferente.no
JOIN emp embalador ON webConferencia.embaladorno = embalador.no
```